# The locus where a sheaf is supported in a certain dimension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves, cohomology, moduli-spaces, flatness

I am trying to understand a particular case of this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122655/what-is-the-structure-of-the-stack-of-complexes-supported-in-dimension-less-than).

Let $T$ be an affine scheme of finite type over the ground field C. Let $X \to T$ be a morphism. I'll assume this to be the base change of a smooth and projective variety over C. In particular $X \to T$ is flat and proper.

Let $E$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$, which I do *not* assume to be flat over $T$ (and this is where the problems come in). Fix a number $r$.
If $t \in T$ is a (geometric) point of $T$, let $E_t$ be the pullback to the fibre $X_t$.
I would like to understand what the locus of points in $T$ such that $E_t$ is supported in dimension at most $r$.

In other words, I want to characterise the subfunctor of $T$, taking an affine $U$ to the set of morphisms $U \stackrel{g}{\to} T$, such that the pullback sheaf $g^*E$ is fiberwise supported in dimension at most $r$.

---

The condition can be phrased with chern characters (or hilbert polynomials I guess), as if $r$ corresponds to codimension $k$ in $X_t$ then I'm looking at the locus where $E_t$ has chern character with zeros in degrees lower than $k$.
If $E$ were flat over $T$ then this locus would be open in $T$.

I suspect this condition for general $E$ should be closed or locally closed, but I can't seem to work it out. One thought would be to use the flattening stratification for $E$ and then impose the condition on chern characters, but that isn't really what we want.
The other thought would be to take some locus where $E$ itself has support of dimension at most $r + \dim T$. 
While it is true that, for any $d$, one can split $E$ in $0 \to E_{\leq d} \to E \to F \to 0$, with $E$ support in dimension at most $d$, I'm not sure taking, say, the schematic image of the (schematic) support of $E_{\leq r + \dim T}$ is the right thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand something, but by Nakayama, the support of $E_t$ is just the support of $E$ intersected with $X_t$, and the support of $E$ is closed in $X$. Let $Z$ be the suppor of $E$. By Chevalley's semi-continuity theorem (EGA, IV.13.1.3), the set of $x\in X$ such that $\dim_x Z_t\le r$ ($x\mapsto t$) is open, so the set of $t\in T$ such that $\dim Z_t\le r$ is constructible in $T$.

This is true for any morphism of finite type $X\to T$ over a noetherian scheme $T$.

Comment: thanks for the answer! (and for the reference), I'll think about it more. Can one use your idea to describe what the _scheme_ parameterising these things looks like? (It's the comment I made before the horizontal line) In other words this constructible subset of T comes with a moduli structure, is it representable?

Comment: As the fiber dimension doesn't change by base change, if there is a scheme which represents your functor, it will be reduced with underlying space equal to the set of $t\in T$ such that $\dim Z_t\le r$. If the latter is locally closed, then endow it with the structure of a reduced subscheme of $T$ and you get a scheme representing your functor. Otherwise I don't know, probably your functor is then not representable.

Comment: Could you please clarify how you deduce reducedness from the fiber dimension?

Comment: sorry for the barrage of comments. Your reference got me reading the wonderful book by Goertz-Wedhorn again, and Corollary 14.113 applied to Z = supp E --> T, seems to suggest that the locus of where the fibre $Z_t$ is of dimension $\geq r+1$ is closed. My foggy brain right now concludes that then the locus I'm interested in is in fact open.

Comment: Yes because in your special case $X\to T$ is proper. As for the reducedness (in the general case), apply your functor to all $U$ affine open in the (moduli scheme)$_{\mathrm{red}}$.

Comment: thank you very much, it is truly precious to have a proper algebraic geometer to talk to!